# How can I make an array of times with half hour intervals?

Tags: php

I needed a list of times like so in an array...

```
12am
12:30am
1:00pm
...
```

How can I do this with PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank-you for reopening the question alex.

This is a solution that should resonate with functional programmers.

```
function halfHourTimes() {
  $formatter = function ($time) {
    if ($time % 3600 == 0) {
      return date('ga', $time);
    } else {
      return date('g:ia', $time);
    }
  };
  $halfHourSteps = range(0, 47*1800, 1800);
  return array_map($formatter, $halfHourSteps);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! I assume it needs PHP 5.3 with the function assigned to a variable? +1 (no worries on re opening, if I knew you were hard at work solving I would never have deleted it).

Answer (score 37):

Here's an improved version of [Alex's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903317/#3903320) that uses seconds for more precision:

```
function hoursRange( $lower = 0, $upper = 86400, $step = 3600, $format = '' ) {
    $times = array();

    if ( empty( $format ) ) {
        $format = 'g:i a';
    }

    foreach ( range( $lower, $upper, $step ) as $increment ) {
        $increment = gmdate( 'H:i', $increment );

        list( $hour, $minutes ) = explode( ':', $increment );

        $date = new DateTime( $hour . ':' . $minutes );

        $times[(string) $increment] = $date->format( $format );
    }

    return $times;
}
```

So, to make an array of times with 1-hour intervals over a 24-hour time period, use the defaults:

```
hoursRange();
```

Which will give you the following:

```
Array
(
    [00:00] => 12:00 am
    [01:00] => 1:00 am
    [02:00] => 2:00 am
    [03:00] => 3:00 am
    [04:00] => 4:00 am
    [05:00] => 5:00 am
    [06:00] => 6:00 am
    [07:00] => 7:00 am
    [08:00] => 8:00 am
    [09:00] => 9:00 am
    [10:00] => 10:00 am
    [11:00] => 11:00 am
    [12:00] => 12:00 pm
    [13:00] => 1:00 pm
    [14:00] => 2:00 pm
    [15:00] => 3:00 pm
    [16:00] => 4:00 pm
    [17:00] => 5:00 pm
    [18:00] => 6:00 pm
    [19:00] => 7:00 pm
    [20:00] => 8:00 pm
    [21:00] => 9:00 pm
    [22:00] => 10:00 pm
    [23:00] => 11:00 pm
)
```

Here are a few example uses:

```
// Every 15 Minutes, All Day Long
$range = hoursRange( 0, 86400, 60 * 15 );

// Every 30 Minutes from 8 AM - 5 PM, using Custom Time Format
$range = hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 30, 'h:i a' );
```

You can view a [working snippet at CodePad](http://codepad.org/QKZO8ymo).

Comment: Looks good - just not sure why you're exploding the `$increment` rather than passing it straight into DateTime constructor?

Comment: Also, you could remove the if (format) and pass that default variable in the function.

Comment: This might be handy to add. It converts a time string to seconds

`/**
 * Takes hour:minutes:seconds (8:15:00) OR minutes:seconds (15:00)
 * @param string $time
 * @return int
 */
function timeToSeconds(string $time): int
{
    $timeParts = explode(':', $time);
    return 3 === count($timeParts) ? $timeParts[0] * 3600 + $timeParts[1] * 60 + $timeParts[2] : $timeParts[0] * 60 + $timeParts[1];
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @rjb rjb for saving my life :)

Answer (score 11):

I decided this one was better :)

```
function hoursRange($lower = 0, $upper = 23, $step = 1, $format = NULL) {

    if ($format === NULL) {
        $format = 'g:ia'; // 9:30pm
    }
    $times = array();
    foreach(range($lower, $upper, $step) as $increment) {
        $increment = number_format($increment, 2);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode('.', $increment);
        $date = new DateTime($hour . ':' . $minutes * .6);
        $times[(string) $increment] = $date->format($format);
    }
    return $times;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can simply use `strtotime` to increment our time by `N` amount here in this case `30 minutes` and `date` function to format it to our desired output.

```
$startTime = strtotime('12 am');
$endTime   = strtotime('11:59 pm');

$arrInterval = [];
while($endTime >= $startTime){
  $arrInterval[] = date("h:ia", $startTime);
  $startTime = strtotime('+30 minutes', $startTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion :

```
    $start = new \DateTime('00:00');
    $times = 24 * 2; // 24 hours * 30 mins in an hour

    for ($i = 0; $i < $times-1; $i++) {
        $result[] = $start->add(new \DateInterval('PT30M'))->format('H:i A');
    }

    print_r($result);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a more elegant way, but it requires the times to be in seconds (that also makes it more flexible).

```
function time_range( $start, $end, $step = 1800 ) {
    $return = array();
    for( $time = $start; $time <= $end; $time += $step )
        $return[] = date( 'g:ia', $time );
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution

```
$h = 0;
while ($h < 24) {
    $key = date('H:i', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' + ' . $h . ' hours'));
    $value = date('h:i A', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' + ' . $h . ' hours'));
    $formatter[$key] = $value;
    $h++;
}
```

Result are:

```
Array
(
    [00:00] => 12:00 AM
    [01:00] => 01:00 AM
    [02:00] => 02:00 AM
    [03:00] => 03:00 AM
    [04:00] => 04:00 AM
    [05:00] => 05:00 AM
    [06:00] => 06:00 AM
    [07:00] => 07:00 AM
    [08:00] => 08:00 AM
    [09:00] => 09:00 AM
    [10:00] => 10:00 AM
    [11:00] => 11:00 AM
    [12:00] => 12:00 PM
    [13:00] => 01:00 PM
    [14:00] => 02:00 PM
    [15:00] => 03:00 PM
    [16:00] => 04:00 PM
    [17:00] => 05:00 PM
    [18:00] => 06:00 PM
    [19:00] => 07:00 PM
    [20:00] => 08:00 PM
    [21:00] => 09:00 PM
    [22:00] => 10:00 PM
    [23:00] => 11:00 PM
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more flexible version that doesn't need DateTime (since we're already working with timestamps in seconds anyway). ;-)

```
function get_hours_range( $start = 0, $end = 86400, $step = 3600, $format = 'g:i a' ) {
        $times = array();
        foreach ( range( $start, $end, $step ) as $timestamp ) {
                $hour_mins = gmdate( 'H:i', $timestamp );
                if ( ! empty( $format ) )
                        $times[$hour_mins] = gmdate( $format, $timestamp );
                else $times[$hour_mins] = $hour_mins;
        }
        return $times;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Added index value as hour:**

*Here is the code:*

```
<?php

    $time_slot= array();
        
        if ( empty( $format ) ) {
            $format = 'H:i';
        }
        $lower = 0; $upper = 86400; $step = 3600; $format = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ( range( $lower, $upper, $step ) as $increment ) {
            $increment = gmdate( 'H:i', $increment );
           
        
             
            $time_slot[$i] = $increment;
            $i++;
        }
    
        print_r($time_slot);

?>
```

*Here is the result:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00:00
    [1] => 01:00
    [2] => 02:00
    [3] => 03:00
    [4] => 04:00
    [5] => 05:00
    [6] => 06:00
    [7] => 07:00
    [8] => 08:00
    [9] => 09:00
    [10] => 10:00
    [11] => 11:00
    [12] => 12:00
    [13] => 13:00
    [14] => 14:00
    [15] => 15:00
    [16] => 16:00
    [17] => 17:00
    [18] => 18:00
    [19] => 19:00
    [20] => 20:00
    [21] => 21:00
    [22] => 22:00
    [23] => 23:00
    [24] => 00:00
)
```