# Create PHP array of Hours, starting now and going backwards 24h

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

I am pulling stats from my database, and grouping them by Hours/days from within mysql.

What I need to create is a PHP array of hours, starting from the current time and going backwards.  So it might look like:

2015-07-07 13:00

2015-07-07 12:00

2015-07-07 11:00

2015-07-07 10:00

...

2015-07-06 13:00

for the array keys.  I will dump my stats into the correct key.

Comment: so where is the problem?

Comment: And what you have tried so far

Comment: I started with this but it takes default values and doesnt start with now:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903317/how-can-i-make-an-array-of-times-with-half-hour-intervals