# Printing out every time block between two time dates php

Tags: php, time

I am trying to print out ever 45 and 75 timestamps between two times.

So far I can calculate how many 45 and 75 blocks are between the two dates.

```
$minutes = abs((new DateTime("5 pm"))->getTimestamp() - (new DateTime('8 am'))->getTimestamp()) / 60;

var_dump([
    '45 minute blocks' => floor($minutes / 45),
    '75 minute blocks' => floor($minutes / 75),
]);
```

What I am trying to do now is print out those timeStamps in between and put them in an array.

what I have so far is this.

```
$m = strtotime('8 am');
$e = strtotime('5 pm');
$total_45 = 0;

while ($e <$m){
  
}
```

anyone know of an easier way to do this in php?

Comment: check my answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903317/how-can-i-make-an-array-of-times-with-half-hour-intervals/63968216#63968216

Comment: A simple way to generate such intervals using `strtotime` and `date` function